# PHPWord reader docx wraps all each text run into new paragraph

Tags: php, phpword

PHPWord read docx files with wrapping of each w:r into new paragraph.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I'll appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been identified and a solution been proposed, see https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1043

The solution has not yet been integrated in the next PHPWord version (0.14) though.

**Update:** This has been fixed in the latest development branch.